# How do I make this specific if statement(in the nested ifs)work?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a text-based tic tac toe game, made of mostly nested ifs. But my 3rd if statement doesn't execute what its supposed to.

I didnt know what do, i was pretty confused, as i am a complete beginner.

```
print("Welcome to the text-based Tic Tac Toe!")
print("  1| 2 |3 ")
print(" ---------")
print("  4| 5 |6 ")
print(" ---------")
print("  7| 8 |9 ")`enter code here`
print("You can choose where you want to place your letter")
print("By choosing the number of that spot or place in the grid")
choice=input("What do you want to be(X/O)?: ")
while(choice=="X"):
    plychoice=int(input("Where would you like to place your letter? "))
    if plychoice==1:*#This is if the player chooses to place their letter in the "1" slot*
     print("  X|   |  ")
     print(" ---------")
     print("   | O |  ")
     print(" ---------enter code here")
     print("   |   |  ")
     plychoice=int(input("Where would you like to place your letter? "))
     if plychoice==9:#This is if the player chooses to place their letter in the "9" slot
         print("  X|   |O ")
         print(" ---------")
         print("   | O |  ")
         print(" ---------")
         print("   |   |X ")
         plychoice==int(input("Where would you like to place your letter? "))
         if plychoice==7:#This is if the player chooses to place their letter in the "7" slot
           print("  X|   |O ")
           print(" ---------")
           print("  O| O |  ")
           print(" ---------")
           print("  X|   |X ")
           plychoice==int(input("Where would you like to place your letter? "))
           if plychoice==8:#This is if the player chooses to place their letter in the "8" slot
               print("  X|   |O ")
               print(" ---------")
               print("  O| O |  ")
               print(" ---------")
               print("  X| X |X ")
               print("YOU WON!!!")
```

i expect the 3rd nested if statement to execute its code.

Comment: improper indentation. the if's should all line up vertically in this code. The way you have it now, it is only checking if `plychoice==1`. So because the others are indented inside the next if statement the others are never checked unless the one above is true.

Comment: Are you entering `1,9,then 7` to the succesive input prompts?

Comment: Also, shouldn't `plychoice==int(input(...)` only have one `=` you are not assigning a value here, you are determining equality.

Comment: In your question, explain in words what is supposed to happen - start at the beginning and describe the process you are trying to implement.   It isn't clear what you want to do.

Comment: oh ya, i am actually not smart. Oh and wwii that is correct, you r entering 1,9,and 7 to the prompts in order.

Comment: Jaba ur solution worked!Oh and wwii u are correct, i was in sort of a hurry, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Are you planning to implement all possible tic tac toe games like this? It might get a bit extensive in code lines.